# About the dimension of the a few vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The set of all real numbers, $\mathbb{R}$, defined over a field of real numbers, $\mathbb{R}$, forms a vector space. What is the dimension of this vector space? I think that dimension is 1. Because any real number can be written in terms of a real multiple of a single real number (say, $1$).

The set of all complex numbers, $\mathbb{C}$, defined over a field of real numbers, $\mathbb{R}$, forms a vector space. I think, in this case, the dimension is 2. This is because any complex number can be expressed in terms of a real multiple of 1 plus a real multiple of $i$.

The set of all complex numbers, $\mathbb{C}$, defined over a field of real numbers, $\mathbb{C}$, forms a vector space. I think, in this case, the dimension is again 1. Any complex number can be expressed as a complex number multiplying a real number (say, $1$).

How correct is my understanding of dimension in these three cases?

Comment: Yes, you are correct in all three cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_(vector_space)) of a vector space $V$ is defined as the number of vectors in a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) for the vector space, and a basis for $V$ is just a [linearly independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence) [spanning set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span) for $V$.

When you say at the end of each paragraph something like

> Because any real number can be written in terms of a real multiple of a single real number

you're describing a basis for each of the vector spaces.

For your first example (call the vector space $V$), the set $\mathcal B=\{1\}$ is linearly independent since $1t=0,t\in\mathbb R$ only has solution $t=0$. It also spans $\mathbb R$ since, for any $x\in\mathbb R$, there exists $t \in \mathbb R$ such that $x=1t$. Hence, $\mathcal B$ is a basis for $V$ with $\mathcal B$ containing one vector. $V$ has dimension $1$.

Your second example (call the vector space $U$) has dimension $2$ because the associated field of scalars has been restricted to $\mathbb R$. That is, a set such as $\{1\}$, although linearly independent, does not span $U$ because any complex number $z\in \mathbb C$ cannot be written as $1t,t\in \mathbb R$. We must add another element to the set to compensate for this restriction. Let $\mathcal C = \{1, i\}$. Now, we have $z=1s+it$ for $ s,t\in\mathbb R$. This new set $\mathcal C$ is linearly independent and spans $\mathbb C$ so it is a basis for $U$.

The third example is similar to the first.

I hope that by sticking to the definitions, I've answered your question clearly.